# Creation sequence in Tree of life?

Tags: analysis, the-tree-of-life

What is the meaning of the creation sequence, a long 20 min scene from The Tree of life? I do not see a clear relation of this scene to the previous one, in which a family has found that a son has died. During the sequence, there is a short story about two dinosaurs and a choice between nature and grace. However, it is unclear to me why it has to be embedded into such a long sequence.

Comment: ["The film chronicles the origins and meaning of life by way of a middle-aged man's childhood memories of his family living in 1950s Texas, interspersed with imagery of the origins of the known universe and the inception of life on Earth."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tree_of_Life_(film))